# Integration of Shared Libraries with external dependacies into MATLAB | ie Armadillo, LAPACK, BLAS

Tags: c, matlab, linker, lapack, armadillo

New to MATLAB and infact, am only dealing with it for simulation purposes. I came across an issue with importing shared libraries into MATLAB. Say I have a complicated set of c source files that require external dependencies, such as Armadillo or LAPACK. what we do is compile the code using gcc or g++ where we link the libraries to the location of these packages.

```
    # Directories and Includes for Lin-Alg Libs
ARMA_INCLUDE = -I../../../armadillo/armadillo-6.600.4/include/
LAPACK_LIB   = -L../../../lapack/lib/
BLAS_LIB     = -L../../../lapack/lib/

ALL_INCLUDES = $(ARMA_INCLUDE) $(LAPACK_LIB) $(BLAS_LIB)

# Target Class
TARGET = target

# Compiler choice | Operation Code
CXX=g++
OPT = -O2

CXXFLAGS = $(CXX) $(OPT)

$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o $(OBJ_FILE)
        g++ -shared -Wl,--export-dynamic $(TARGET).o -o $(TARGET).so $(ALL_INCLUDES) $(LIB_FLAGS)

$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).cpp
    $(CXXFLAGS) $(ARMA_LIB) $(ALL_INCLUDES) $(LIB_FLAGS) -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -c target.cpp
```

This works and I can call the libraries exactly how I intend. Now I go into the matlab environment and type the following.

```
loadlibrary(target.so, 'target.h')
```

I get the following error message...

```
Error using loadlibrary
Failed to preprocess the input file.
 Output from preprocessor is target.h:1:21: fatal error:
 armadillo: No such file or directory
 #include <armadillo>
                     ^
compilation terminated.


Error in MOculusEKF (line 5)
loadlibrary('target.so', 'target.h')
```

I get that there is an issue with MATLAB and not seeing the location of the armadillo libraries, but I've not found anything on linking them together.

The following makes sense but armadillo isn't packaged into a dll, its a simple script.

```
addpath('C:\Users\Dustin\armadillo\armadillo-6.600.4\include');
loadlibrary('armadillo')
```

followed by a call to load target.so.

I'm also aware that I could use mex to solve this issue but that would require ALOT of conversion code, if I could avoid that, it would be nice.

```
mex -larmadillo -lgfortran target.so
```

As I've said the above would be alot of work. I'm looking for a way to specify -larmadillo somehow in loadlibrary.

Any advice??
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that Matlab requires a mxArray type as input/output. Armadillo library for example uses Mat, Col etc. You probably need to compile it to a mex file first. As an example to build with Armadillo and Lapack you may look at my work: http://sigpack.sourceforge.net/build.html